# accessing jquery appended elements from external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**test.html**

```
<body>
    <div id="parent" onclick="testFn('parent')">This is a basic test</div>
    <script>
        function testFn(id) {
            $('#' + id).load("appended.html");
            console.log(document.getElementById(id));
            console.log(document.getElementById("appendedDiv"));
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

**appended.html**

```
<div id="appendedDiv">appended!</div>
```

The first console.log correctly returns the "parent" element, and I can see in the output that the parent element has a correctly appended the "appendedDiv", but the second console.log returns null. Why can't it find the "appendedDiv" even though I can see that it has clearly been appended? (this is a simplified version of my problem, and it is necessary that I do append an external html file)

Comment: what happens when you do var mydiv = $("#appendedDiv").html(); console.log(mydiv); ?   Or how about mydiv = $("#" + id).find("#appendedDiv").html(); console.log(mydiv);

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `load` callback. It will run when the `load` is completed.

```
function testFn(id) {
    $('#' + id).load("appended.html", function() {
        // Loaded Completely
        console.log($('#appendedDiv'));
    });
}
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/load/

> A callback function that is executed when the request completes.

Answer (score 1):

Since [`$.fn.load`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) is asynchronous you need to use its callback method. Where callback function is executed when the request completes.

```
$('#' + id).load("appended.html",function (){
    console.log(document.getElementById("appendedDiv"));
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to use load as a synchronous function, and somehow block the rest of the processes until it has completed?

Comment: @doomba yes go through the link and look for $.ajax()

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
var myvar = $.load("appended.html");
$("#".id).append(myvar.html());
var mychild = $("#appendedDiv").html();
console.log(mychild);
```